# Graphical Audio player in iOS

Tags: iphone

Is there a library or built in graphical player to represent a playing audio file in iOS.

I dont want a full screen player, but a small inline player that can be embedded into a UIView.

Does this exist in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a good example of this, avTouch. I have successfully adapted parts of their code to display audio levels in the past.

[avTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008636-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)